# Is there a way to use bearing in here explorer SDK

Tags: android-studio, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

Currently this is the icon i use to track the drivers position as it moves on the map :
[driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE9Nl.png)

so if the driver turns right or left ,the marker keeps pointing at the same direction and i wanted to make use of BEARING .
But as far as my research went, i am not able to do that with heremaps if im using the explorer edition because i'd need a 3d icon.

But is there a way to do that with 2d icons that im missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to do this and forgot to reply to myself, and i did it through Location Indicator object. it allows the user to use a predefined 3d marker and it behaves exactly like i want it to.

more on :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.4.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html

even tho it says *navigate* here, *explorer* sdk has the same object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to rotate the marker image. Indeed, this cannot be done with the `MapMarker` class. Instead create a flat marker, like in this [example](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/d07e4af93b2db946a1f97fdc12cfd6f4b0a760fc/examples/latest/explore/android/MapItems/app/src/main/java/com/here/mapitems/MapItemsExample.java#L245).

The *Explore Edition* fully supports 3D icons, so there's no reason not to use them.

A `MapMarker3D` instance can be created right-aways from a PNG image - just like a 2D `MapMarker`. See also [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.11.4.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#add-flat-map-markers) and scroll to the end of the chapter.

Comment: I did find a way to do this and forgot to reply to myself, and i did it through Location Indicator object.
it allows the user to use a predefined 3d marker and it behaves exactly like i want it to.
more on 

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.4.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html

even tho it says navigate here, explorer sdk has the same objects.

the only thing im struggling to find is how to update the camera with the current bearing with a smooth transition, i do know how to update it but it kinda teleports. 
thanks nusatad !